# On navigating from one Component to Second , previous compoennt remains in View Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

While routing from one component to the second component , first component stays in view. It is removed if the page is reloaded once. Routing is done using a button click
and code for following is

`this.router.navigate(['/component_b']);`

Using a button click in component_A typescript file.

```
 "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"


export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home' , component: FirstComponent },
    {path: 'component_a' , component: AComponent},
    {path: 'component_b', component: BComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}

];
```

Is there a method to remove the first-component from staying in view when router module brings control to the second-component for the first time

Comment: if you are in the route `/component_a`, there is no reason the route `/home` appears in the page. The only reason could be `FirstComponent` is hard coded in your `app.component.html`. Can you show its content ?

Comment: Can you try this.router.navigate(['./component_b']);

Comment: `<!--The content of app.component.html -->
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
`

Comment: Have also tried  `this.router.navigate(['./component_b']);` didnt help

Comment: when i reload the page the previous component disappears from the view

Comment: Facing the same issue? did you found any luck?